# Матрица по принципу игры 2048

Tags: javascript

У нас есть 4 размерный массив. Нужно написать программу, который сложит ровный его число, который направо, а его сделает 0, но только один раз.

```
function solution(x){
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
          if (x[i][j]==x[i][j+1]) {
              x[i][j]=0
              x[i][j+1]*=2
          }
      } 
  }
  return JSON.stringify(x)
}

console.log(solution([[2,2,4,8],
                      [4,8,4,8],
                      [8,8,8,8],
                      [64,8,16,8]]))
```

> он вернет

```
  [0,0,0,16],
  [4,8,4,8],
  [0,16,0,16],
  [64,8,16,8]
```

> но нужно чтобы второй раз не сложил,то есть вместо  [0,0,0,16], нужно [0,4,4,8]

Нужно чтобы программа работал правильно,для всех таких примеров,но в это время был очень простым..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> x[i][j+1]*=2
> ```

```
x[i][++j]*=2
```

```js
function solution(x){
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
          if (x[i][j]==x[i][j+1]) {
              x[i][j]=0
              x[i][++j]*=2
          }
      } 
  }
  return JSON.stringify(x)
}

console.log(solution([[2,2,4,8],
                      [4,8,4,8],
                      [8,8,8,8],
                      [64,8,16,8]]))
```

Comment: конечно это вариант,но только в примере,который я написал,но есть матрицы,при которых код не работает,что можете предлагать?

Comment: Я их угадать должен?

Comment: просто у меня тест со скрытыми матрицами,я тоже не могу угадать,нет варианта где код всегда будет работать?

Comment: @TyomArshakyan, я исправил.

Comment: оу,круто,спасибо большое)))